# javascript loading time when using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

What's the difference between the following codes?

```
require (['something'], function(something) {

  something.foo();
});
```

vs

```
require(['something'], function(something) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
     something.foo();
  }
});
```

I see all the examples use `require` on `<head>` instead of at the bottom of `<body>`.
I thought js is better located at the bottom in order to not to delay page loading.

Besides, if javascript module is loaded (in any chance) before the page loads, the assumption, of my pre-requirejs-javascript, which doms are already loaded isn't true anymore.
Should I not use requirejs for such javascripts?